# How to use single drawable for all screen resolutions in Android programming?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, drawable, android-drawable

Android programming in eclipse, java, xml etc. I put all the drawables (images, xml files etc) in all the folders: mdpi, hdpi etc. So I have 4 copies of each file.

Is this absolutely necessary ?

Is there a way I can put them in a single "drawable" folder ?

Or will android understand that if the file does not exist in hdpi, it should fetch it from mdpi, or wherever the file exists ?

Comment: yes it will ftech the appropriate file if that particular image is not available in other folder

Comment: Thanks, please post this as an answer.

Comment: ["How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) - make sure you read the whole page, not just the one section.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, it will fetch the appropriate file if that particular image is
>   not available in other folder. But it need to atlest in one folder(drawable OR mdpi OR hdpi OR ldpi ...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can put all the images in single drawable folder.But in this case if you have a low resolution image this will be look as faded image in the case of tabs

so if you want your application support in all devices, Tabs then you have to put images in different drawable folder like as drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi

Answer (score 1):

Why not use https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/ to automatically resize your images to all resolution compatible for android development?

Comment: This seems good. I will probably need this at some point. Thank you !